# Setting and clearing the zero flag in x86

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, x86-64, micro-optimization

What's the most efficient way to set and also to clear the zero flag (ZF) in x86-64?

Methods that work without the need for a register with a known value, or without any free registers at all are preferred, but if a better method is available when those or other assumptions are true it is also worth mentioning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### ZF=0

This is harder.  `cmp` between any two regs known to be not equal.  Or `cmp reg,imm` with any value some reg couldn't possibly have.  e.g. `cmp reg,1` with any known-zero register.

**In general `test reg,reg` is good with any known-non-0 register value, e.g. a pointer**.
**`test rsp, rsp` is probably a good choice,** or even `test esp, esp` to save a byte will work except if your stack is in the unusual location of spanning a 4G boundary.

I don't see a way to create ZF=0 in one instruction without a false dependency on some input reg.  `xor eax,eax` / `inc eax` or `dec` will do the trick in 2 uops if you don't mind destroying a register, breaking false dependencies.  (`not` doesn't set FLAGS, and `neg` will just do 0-0 = 0.)

**`or eax, -1` doesn't need any pre-condition for the register value.**  (False dependency, but not a true dependency so you can pick any register even if it might be zero.)  It doesn't have to be `-1`, it's not gaining you anything so if you can make it something useful so much the better.

**`or eax,-1` FLAG results: ZF=0 PF=1 SF=1 CF=0 OF=0  (AF=undefined).**

If you need to do this in a loop, you can obviously set up for it *outside* the loop, if you can dedicate a register to being non-zero for use with `test`.

---

### ZF=1

Least destructive: `cmp eax,eax` - but has a false dependency (I assume) and needs a back-end uop: not a zeroing idiom.  RSP doesn't usually change much so `cmp esp, esp` could be a good choice. (Unless that forces a stack-sync uop).

Most efficient: **[xor-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/) (like `xor eax,eax` using any free register) is definitely the most efficient way on SnB-family (same cost as a 2-byte `nop`**, or 3-byte if it needs a REX because you want to zero one of r8d..r15d): 1 front-end uop, **zero back-end uops** on SnB-family, and the FLAGS result is ready in the same cycle it issues.  (Relevant only in case the front-end was stalled, or some other case where a uop depending on it issues in the same cycle and there aren't any older uops in the RS with ready inputs, otherwise such uops would have priority for whichever execution port.)

**Flag results: ZF=1 PF=1 SF=0 CF=0 OF=0  (AF=undefined).**    (Or use `sub eax,eax` to get well-defined AF=0.  In practice modern CPUs pick AF=0 for xor-zeroing, too, so they can decode both zeroing idioms the same way.  Silvermont only recognizes 32-bit operand-size xor as a zeroing idiom, not sub.)

xor-zero is very cheap on all other uarches as well, of course: no input dependencies, and doesn't need any pre-existing register value.  (And thus doesn't contribute to P6-family register-read stalls).  So it will be at worst tied with anything else you could do on any other uarch (where it does require an execution unit.)

(On early P6-family, before Pentium M, `xor`-zeroing does *not* break dependencies; it only triggers the special al=eax state that avoids partial-register stuff.  But none of those CPUs are x86-64, all 32-bit only.)

It's pretty common to want a zeroed register for something anyway, e.g. as a `sub` destination for `0 - x` to copy-and-negate, so take advantage of it by putting the xor-zeroing where you need it to also create a useful FLAG condition.

Interesting but probably not useful: `test al, 0` is 2 bytes long.  But so is `cmp esp,esp`.

---

**As @prl suggested, `cmp same,same` with any register will work without disturbing a value**.  I suspect this is *not* special-cased as dependency breaking the way `sub same,same` is on some CPUs, so **pick a "cold" register**.  Again 2 or 3 bytes, 1 uop.  It can micro-fuse with a JCC, but that would be dumb (unless the JCC is also a branch target from some other condition?)

Flag results: same as xor-zeroing.

Downsides:

- (probably) false dependency
- on P6-family can contribute to a register-read stall, so pick a cold register you're already reading in nearby instructions.
- needs a back-end execution unit on SnB-family

---

Just for fun, other as-cheap alternatives include `test al, 0`.  2 bytes for AL, 3 or 4 bytes for any other 8-bit register.  (REX) + opcode + modrm + imm8.  The original register value doesn't matter because an `imm8` of zero guarantees that `reg & 0 = 0`.

---

If you happen to have a `1` or `-1` in a register you can destroy, 32-bit mode `inc` or `dec` would set ZF in only 1 byte.  But in x86-64 that's at least 2 bytes.  Nothing comes to mind for a 1-byte instruction in 64-bit mode that's actually efficient and sets FLAGS.

---

### ZF=!CF

`sbb same,same` can set ZF=!CF (leaving CF unmodified), and setting the reg to 0 (CF=0) or -1 (CF=1).  On AMD since Bulldozer (BD-family and Zen-family), this has no dependency on the GP register, only CF. But on other uarches it's not special cased and there is a false dep on the reg.  And it's 2 uops on Intel before Broadwell.

---

### ZF=!bool(integer register)

To set ZF=!integer_reg, obviously the normal [`test reg,reg` is your best bet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  (Better than `and reg,reg` or `or reg,reg`, unless you're intentionally rewriting the register to avoid P6 register-read stalls.)

ZF=1 if the register value is zero, so it's like C's logical inverse operator.

##### ZF=!ZF

Perhaps `setz al` / `test al, al`.  No single instruction: I don't think any read ZF and write FLAGS.  `setz` materializes ZF in a register, then `test` is just `ZF = !reg`.

---

### Other FLAGS conditions:

- [How to read and write x86 flags registers directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406783/how-to-read-and-write-x86-flags-registers-directly)
- [One instruction to clear PF (Parity Flag) -- get odd number of bits in result register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259759/one-instruction-to-clear-pf-parity-flag-get-odd-number-of-bits-in-result-re) (not possible without pre-existing register values for `test` or `cmp`).
- [How can I set or clear overflow flag in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798572/how-can-i-set-or-clear-overflow-flag-in-x86-assembly) (e.g. for the start of an ADOX chain.)
- `pushf`/`pop rax` is not terrible, but writing flags with `popf` is very slow (e.g. 1/20c throughput on SKL).  It's microcoded because flags like IF also live in EFLAGS, and there isn't a condition-codes-only version or a special fast-path for user-space.  (Or maybe 20c *is* the fast path.)
- `lahf` (FLAGS->AH) / `sahf` (AH->FLAGS) can be useful but miss OF.

CF has `clc`/`stc`/`cmc` instructions.  (`clc` is as efficient as xor-zeroing on SnB-family.)

Comment: I believe `sbb reg, reg` sets ZF = ! CF. As CF = 1 leads to FFFFh, CY, NZ and CF = 0 leads to 0000h, NC, ZR.

Comment: @ecm: Right, thanks, fixed.  I probably got mixed up between register = 0 but ZF=1 when thinking that through originally.

Comment: What about complimenting/inverting `ZF = !ZF` (similar to `CMC`)? Is there a "reasonable" way to do that?

Comment: @640KB: Not with a single instruction, but perhaps `setz al` / `test al, al`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don’t need to preserve the values of the other flags,

```
cmp eax, eax
```

Answer (score 3):

The least intrusive way to manipulate any<sup>(i)</sup> of the lower 8 bits of Flags is to use the classic [`LAHF`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lahf)/[`SAHF`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sahf) instructions which bring them to/from AH, on which any bit operation can be applied.
<sup>(i)</sup> Just bits 7 (SF), 6 (ZF), 4 (AF), 2 (PF), and 0 (CF)

#### Turning off ZF

```
       LAHF                      ; Load lower 8 bit from Flags into AH
       AND      AH,010111111b    ; Clear bit for ZF
       SAHF                      ; Store AH back to Flags
```

#### Turning on ZF

```
       LAHF                      ; Load AH from FLAGS
       OR       AH,001000000b    ; Set bit for ZF
       SAHF                      ; Store AH back to Flags
```

Of course any `CMP (E)AX,(E)AX` will set ZF faster and with less code; the point of this is to leave other FLAGS unmodified, as in *[How to read and write x86 flags registers directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406783)* and *[how to change flags manually (in assembly code) for 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39816491)*

#### CAVEAT for early AMD64 - LAHF in long mode is an extension

Some very early x86-64 CPU's, most notably all

- **AMD Athlon 64**, Opteron and Turion 64 **before revision D** (March 2005) and
- **Intel before Pentium 4 stepping G1*** (December 2005)

As that instruction was originally removed from the AMD64 instruction subset, but later reintroduced. Luckily that happened before x86-64 became a common sight, so only a few, early-on high-end CPUs are affected and even less, surviving today. More so as these are the CPUs that are not able to run Windows 10, or any 64-bit Windows before Windows 10 (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/941175) at SuperUser.SE).

If you really expect that someone might try to run that software on a more than 17 year old high-end CPU, it can be checked for by executing [`CPUID`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid) with EAX=80000001h and test for 2^0=1.